# How to use JSON.NET to serialize static properties on a type that implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider

Tags: json.net, dynamic-language-runtime

I have a class that implements IDynamicMetaObjectProvider in order to support dynamic properties in addition to the compile time properties already defined on the class.  When I serialize instances of this type with JsonConvert.SerializeObject, the resulting JSON string only seems to include the dynamic properties.  Is there a setting to have it serialize both the dynamic and statically defined properties?

Comment: Have you already solved the problem? if yes can you post the answer. If not can you describe the problem with a small example?. I have been asked do something similar, so...